# Deploy Github - Problem deploying with github actions

Tags: angular, github-actions

I´m trying to deploy mi simple angular project in github actions. I try something like this

**Script**

```
"deploy": "ng build --configuration=production --base-href=/angular-crud/"
```

**Deploy.yml**

```
name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
    
    on:
      push:
        branches:
          - main
    
    jobs:
      deploy:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
        steps:
          - name: Checkout repository
            uses: actions/checkout@v3
    
          - name: Set up Node.js
            uses: actions/setup-node@v2.5.0
            with:
              node-version: 16
    
          - name: Install dependencies
            run: npm ci
    
          - name: Build
            run: npm run-script deploy
    
          - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
            uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
            with:
              github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
              publish_dir: ./dist
```

**Angular.json**

```
"outputPath": "dist",
```

**Branch**

https://github.com/ElHombreSinNombre/angular-crud/tree/gh-pages

The problem as we can see here returns 404

**Web**

https://elhombresinnombre.github.io/angular-crud/

So, anybody see what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What looks wrong to me, is the URL you're requesting to visit the site:

https://elhombresinnombre.github.io/angular-crud/ ([archived copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20230521085237/https://elhombresinnombre.github.io/angular-crud/))

The correct URL to request the site is:

https://elhombresinnombre.github.io/angular-crud/apollo-crud/index.html ([archived copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20230521085143/https://elhombresinnombre.github.io/angular-crud/apollo-crud/index.html))

Because as the [deployment revision of the `gh-pages` branch shows](https://github.com/ElHombreSinNombre/angular-crud/commit/b2045fdaa8b6aa09815329145d8f79ca532f6232), the index.html file is placed in that subfolder.

The deployment revision is easy to find as there is only a single deployment so far ([list of all your gh-pages deployments to far](https://github.com/ElHombreSinNombre/angular-crud/deployments/activity_log?environment=github-pages)).

---

What is in effect here?

Mind the `--base-href` option argument for the `ng build` command in the `deploy` npm script:

```json
"deploy": "ng build --configuration=production --base-href=/angular-crud/"
```

together with the `angular.json#/projects/apollo-crud/architect/build/options/outputPath`:

```json
            "outputPath": "dist/apollo-crud",
```

and the `publish_dir` setting in the workflow:

```yaml
          - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
            uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
            with:
              github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
              publish_dir: ./dist
```

and compare them against the Microsoft Github Pages configuration of your repository (it also has a directory option).

E.g. you may want to use the default output directory of the Ansible project (`dist` only) to lower the barrier of entry as it would spare the `apollo-crud` subdirectory and looks matching with the `publish_dir` input parameter of the `peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3` action. But that is entirely up to you, AFAIK all the utilities in the belt support diverse path layouts for Microsoft Github Pages for your Ansible projects, and there are more than one way to configure them so that the orchestra plays the same song.

Comment: So,

This is correct? https://github.com/ElHombreSinNombre/angular-crud/tree/gh-pages

Anyway, https://elhombresinnombre.github.io/angular-crud/ keeps returning 404 error

Comment: @ElHombreSinNombre: Yes, that tree has index.html in the root directory, however you have not deployed that revision yet. That is the reason you still see the 404 error, this is still your first deployment with the subdirectory as written about in the answer. [your list of deployments](https://github.com/ElHombreSinNombre/angular-crud/deployments/activity_log?environment=github-pages)